# Problem with first order linear ODE formula.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I'm working at this simple linear first order ODE:
$$y'+y=e^{x}$$
Rewriting as:
$$y'=-y+e^{x}$$
I want to apply the formula:
$$y(t)=e^{\int a(t)dt}\int e^{-\int a(t)dt}b(t)dt$$
Where, in this particular case, $a(t)=-1$ and $b(t)=e^{x}$.

So, $$A(t)=-x+c$$
$$B(t)=e^{x}+c$$
Are a primitives for $a(t)$ and $b(t)$.
But, if i put these primitives int the formula I can't get the result. Where is my mistake? Have I misunderstood the formula? Thank you.

Comment: According to the formula, shouldnt A(t) be = -y +c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'+y=e^{x}$$
Multiply both side by $e^x$
$$y'e^x+ye^x=e^{2x}$$
$$(ye^x)'=e^{2x}$$
Integrate 
$$(ye^x)=\int e^{2x}dx$$
therefore the solution is
$$\boxed{y=e^{-x}( \frac {e^{2x}}2+K) \implies y(x)=Ke^{-x}+ \frac {e^{x}}2}$$
No the question you ask what is the exact formula ?
$$y'=-y+e^{t}$$
$$y'=a(t)y+b(t)$$
$$y(t)=e^{\int a(t)dt}\int e^{-\int a(t)dt}b(t)dt$$
here $a(t)=-1$
$$y(t)=e^{-t}\int e^{t}b(t)dt$$
and $b(t)=e^t$
$$y(t)=e^{-t}\int e^{2t}dt$$
I add some lines for the integral its just integration of the exponential

$$I=\int e^{2t}dt=\frac {e^{2t}}2+K$$
$$\boxed{y(t)=Ke^{-t}+ \frac {e^{t}}2}$$

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. My attempt was to rigorously apply the well know formula I reported above, but I cant tell why that formula don't get me to th result.

Comment: I put the equation in that order: $y'=-a(x)y+b(x)$. Is this ok? Thank you.

Comment: It depends ont the textbook sometimes they write it this or the other way

Comment: For istance, my text book says:$$y'=ay+b$$
and $A(t)=at$ and $B(t)=-b/a(e^{-at})$. But I can't explain it.
Expecially for $B(t)$. Thank you.

Comment: I see I need to check your calculation but in your formula you only have a and b not A and B

Comment: Ok, I saw your calculation and it's ok, the result is correct. But I still have a little bit troubles understening your last two lines. Thank you.

Comment: What dont you understanf in the last line ? @muserock92

Comment: Computing the integral I have $$ e^{-t}[\frac{t^2e^{2}}{2}+K]$$

Comment: There is no x the integral of $\int e^{2t}dt=\frac {e^{2t}}2 +C$ @muserock92

Comment: Ok, It's just me doing wrong the integral. Thanks for the support, I'll vote your answer :)
Last question: do you know why my text book write, in that generic case, $B(t)$ in such way? Thank you so much.

Comment: Yu cant mix two variables you either choose x or t as the variable but not both...I choose from the beginning t ...with your formula

Comment: Oh maybe for some other purpose but here your formula works fine without A and B ...just put your equation in the correct form of the textbook...@muserock92

Comment: Yes, you've definitely right. Thank you :).

Comment: yw @muserock92....

Comment: Thanks Moo......